# NVM cannot find installed Node binary, PATH problem on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, node.js, javascript

I've successfully installed NVM and Node using official instructions. My `.bashrc` file contains

```
[ -s "/home/user/.nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/home/user/.nvm/nvm.sh"
```

After some time, maybe a day, I noticed that Node is not present anymore . So I tried:

```
$ nvm use 0.10
N/A version is not installed yet
```

That's weird, I know that I installed it with `nvm install 0.10` , used it to run a script, and found it here:

```
$ ls .nvm/v0.10.29/
bin  ChangeLog  include  lib  LICENSE  README.md  share
```

So, everything looks right, but NVM simply doesn't work:

```
$ nvm install 0.10
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/mdm/bin’: Permission denied
Binary download failed, trying source.
Additional options while compiling: 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/mdm/src’: Permission denied
nvm: install v0.10.29 failed!

$ nvm deactivate
Could not find /etc/mdm/*/bin in $PATH
Could not find /etc/mdm/*/share/man in $MANPATH
Could not find /etc/mdm/*/lib/node_modules in $NODE_PATH
```

Output shows that nvm is trying to use /etc/mdm/* dir, and this doesn't make any sense. MDM is display manager in Linux Mint. Any ideas ?

UPDATE: 
just checked now, seems that $NVM_DIR is set to /etc/mdm. That's probably why everything fails, but don't know when this get set, or why.

UPDATE 2(FIX):

```
export NVM_DIR=/home/user/.nvm
```

will fix this problem.

Comment: Your fix has already been integrated with the master branch in the GitHub repo. Also, you should post your fix as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From Preference -> Package Settings -> NodeJs -> User Setting
Add:

```
{
// save before running commands
"save_first": true,
// if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
// e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
"node_command": "/usr/local/bin/node",
// Same for NPM command
"npm_command": "/usr/local/bin/npm",
// as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
"node_path": false,

"expert_mode": false,

"ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```